# CSS display table width 100% cells behavior

Tags: css

I am trying to use the div with display table.
I'd like that the first cell take 100% of length less than the space occupied by the second cell. 
the second cell must occupy only the space of the text.
I tried in this way but without success.

HTML

```
<div class="tbl">
   <div class="t1">text 1</div>
   <div class="t2">text 2 3 4 5</div>
</div>

<div class="tbl">
   <div class="t11">text 1</div>
   <div class="t2">text 2 3 4 5</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.tbl {
display: table;
border: 1px solid #ccc;
width: 100%;
}

.t1, 
.t2 {
display: table-cell;
}

.t1 {
background: red;
width: 100%;
}

.t2 {
background: yellow;
}

.t11 {
background: red;
}
```

How could I do that? thanks

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/gya48mbq/2/)

Comment: Just to clarify, you want the first cell to have a width of `100% - second_cell_width` right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `white-space: nowrap` to the second cell. This works for the top cell pair. For the second pair, you can just add `display: table-cell; width: 100%` as you had with the top pair and it'll work.

[the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xdsk3ymw/)

Comment: the two solutions seem identical. The solution (nowrap) works even if instead of the text I insert a div? thanks

Comment: @Dexter No, I don't think it will work with a nested `div`, however, a nested `div` will interact with the parent `div` in a different way. That is a different question and there's plenty of information on how to handle sizing of nested `div`s online and on stackoverflow. - By the way, is there any reason you can't use `<table>` instead?

Comment: I wanted to avoid using tables. I'll try on Stackoverflow how to get the same result using the div inline-block. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Dexter just a tip, avoiding tables is ok, but make sure you know _why_ you're avoiding them - people discourage using things like `table` for specific reasons, which may not apply to your case. Anyway, good luck :)